# Avoid accidental \\*

Tags: best-practices

When you write in LaTeX some like:

```
A\\ %
*A
```

You expect see the asterisk before of the second character, as usual in any  text. However, the above chunk  is equivalent to write:

```
A\\* %
A
```

That is, the asterisk will be a part of the command `\\*`, and therefore `*` is not showed.

Of course, one can use several tricks to show the phantom asterisk:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
A\\ 
\textasteriskcentered A\\ %
\**A\\%
{}*A\\
\mbox{*}A\\ %
\end{document}
```

But I wonder if there are  better approaches. Specially, if there are a way to prevent the sticking of `\\` to `*` without touch the body of the document.

Comment: Don't use ``\\*``, it's easier.

Comment: You could redefine it to remove the `\@ifstar` component. Check out its definition in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx).

Comment: You should almost never need `\\ ` outside tabular and math alignments, and for the latter the ams alignments all redefine \\ _not_ to step past white space while looking for `*` and `[`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Almost never I use \\ outside of a table, but this is only a MWE, I thinked about this... (let us call  "problem") when making the mistake in a table with `tabulary` (N.B.: And I almost never I start  table rows with  asterisks, but there are tables and tables ...).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you make your comment an answer? Perhaps you could cover the reasons for the default behaviour and the discussions the ream have had in this area?

Comment: @Werner, your comment seem the eligible answer if you show how refedine `\\*` (It's not a normal command). Do you expect many side-effects doing this ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not only "for the latter". Surprisingly  `\usepackage{amsmath}` also fix the "problem" in tabular and plain text mode. Look like the simplest solution, since is a common package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply including  `\usepackage{amsmath}` the problem is solved across all the documment, surprinsingly (at least for me) also in plain text or simple tables.

In the MWE below, all the asteriks are showed. If the package is removed, then  `*12` is  always rendered as `12`, without the asterisk.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 *11  *22\\
 *12  *32\\

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    *11 & *22\\
    *12 & *32\\
\end{tabular}

$
*11 *22\\
*12 *32\\
$
\end{document}
```

Note: I answer my own question marked as "community wiki" to remove it from the unanswered list, but since David's comment put me on the runway, I hope that Josehp's comment does not fall on deaf ears in order to accept one. `;)`